# Integral mean inequalities

Tags: integral-inequality

If $f \in C[0,1]$, then should be true that
$$\left( \int |f|^p\right)^{1/p} \leq \left( \int |f|^q\right)^{1/q}$$
for $1<p \leq q$. However, I have found no sources on this fact. Is it true?

Comment: This is the integral version of the [Generalized Mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean) Inequality.

Comment: Have you tried Jensen's inequality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows from [Hölder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder's_inequality). Letting $r$ denote the Hölder conjugate of $\frac{q}{p}$, we have $$\|f\|_p^p = \|f^p\|_1 \leq \|f^p\|_{q/p}\|1\|_r = \|f^p\|_{q/p} = \|f\|_q^p$$ so $\|f\|_p \leq \|f\|_q$. More generally, if $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ is a finite measure space, the same proof shows that $\|f\|_p \leq \|f\|_q\mu(X)^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is also a direct consequence of [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality)

Since $\varphi(x)=x^\frac{q}{p}$ is convex, we obtain

$$ \left(\int |f|^p\right)^{\frac{q}{p}}\varphi\left(\int |f|^p\right) \leq \int \varphi(|f|^p) = \int |f|^q$$
Taking the $q$-th root shows the result.